# React useNavigate is erroring as not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in previous React version I was able to use Redirect to change from one page to another when using some condition on if it would change. But with v6 redirect is no longer usable.

```
import React, {useState, Redirect, useNavigate} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Main() {
    const handleLogInUsernameChange = (event) => {
        setLogInUsername(event.target.value)
    }

    const handleLogInPasswordChange = (event) => {
        setLogInPassword(event.target.value)
    }

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    function RedirectTo(){
        navigate('/dashboard')
    }

    function checkLogInCred(){
        fetch("https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/").then(res=>{
            if (res.status === 200){
                // SUCCESS
                res.json().then(data=>{
                    const yourData = data
                    for(var a = 0; a < yourData.data.length - 1;a++){
                        if(yourData.data[a].Password === logInPassword &&
                            yourData.data[a].UserName === logInUsername)
                            {
                                logInStatus = "Logged"
                                console.log("You have logged in")
                                a = yourData.data.length
                                //<Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                                RedirectTo()
                            }
                    }
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
            else{
                // ERROR
            }
        })
        //navigate('/dashboard')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" onChange={handleLogInUsernameChange}></input>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password" onChange={handleLogInPasswordChange}></input>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button onClick={checkLogInCred}>Login</button> 
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

Seems like everything is only working in onClick functions only

Answer (score 0):

```
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
```

useNavigate is part of react-router-dom not React.

In your case, it will be something like:

```
import {Link,useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: OMG!!! felt like a total idiot .......thank you all very much resolved the issue. As the above said had the import from the wrong section

Comment: If this answer helped you out, please accept it :) @WilliamPescherine

Answer (score 0):

useNavigate is imported from react-router-dom, so in your case:

> import {Link,useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

Answer (score 0):

you are importing it from then react.

```
import React, {useState, Redirect, useNavigate} from 'react';
```

import it from react-router-dom

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

hope it will resolve the redirection.